# Parse SLURM job wall time to bash variables

Tags: bash, date, time, slurm

With SLURM, I run the command

```
squeue -u enter_username
```

and I get an table output with the following heading

```
JOBID PARTITION     NAME     USER ST       TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
```

I'm trying to capture the duration of time the job has been running for. I couldn't find an environmental variable provided by SLURM to capture this time, so I think I'm left parsing the output of `squeue`. This is not as easy as I thought it would be, because the wall clock does not have a fixed format. In other words, it doesn't always show dd-HH:MM:SS. If there are no days, then the output is just HH:MM:SS, and if there are no hours the output is MM:SS, etc.

I'm doing this with bash and I need to capture the day (dd) and hour (HH) and assign each of them to a variable. I'm having a hard time doing this when the format is dynamic.

To capture the time entry, I'm simply doing the following (within a SLURM bash script)

```
 time_str=$(squeue -u enter_username | grep "$SLURM_JOB_ID" | cut -d "R" -f2- | gawk '{print $1}')
```

As I said before, `time_str` does not have a fixed format. Hoping someone with experience can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the man page of the `squeue` command, it seems that you can simplify the problem by having `squeue` only output the information you need:

```
squeue -h -j ${jobid} -O timeused
```

Then your task is simply to parse that output, which can be done as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

line="-$(squeue -h -j ${jobid} -O timeused)" # Leading '-' aids parsing.

parts=( 0 0 0 0 )
index=3
while [ ${#line} -gt 0 ]; do
  parts[${index}]=${line##*[-:]}
  line=${line%[-:]*}
  ((index--))
done
```

Now the array `${parts[*]}` contains exactly 4 elements, 0 to 3, representing days, hours, minutes and seconds respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented by @Andrew Vickers above works as expected. However, I took this one step further to enforce a fixed 2 digit format

```
index=0
while [ ${index} -lt 4 ]; do
    if [ ${#parts[${index}]} -lt 2 ]; then
        parts[${index}]="0${parts[${index}]}"
    fi
((index++))
done
```

The conditional check could be incorporated into his answer, but his loop would need to be adjusted to format all variables.

Comment: I generally find it better to format output when you are displaying it, rather than when you are storing it internally. To format output with leading zeros, use the printf command: `printf "%d Days, %02d:%02d:%02d" ${parts[@]}`.